# FrameLayout next to another

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using mapview and overlap layouts on map. I would like to set FrameLayout(frame_layout_visible) next to another FrameLayout(framelayout2). How can i do it? I don't know what i am doing wrong but  `android:layout_toRightOf` it's not working.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ActionMenuView
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        
        android:id="@+id/toolbarMap1" />

    <com.esri.android.map.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:src="@drawable/map"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarMap1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus1" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarMap1"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout_visible"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_60sdp">
         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageZwin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/drag_drop"/>
        </FrameLayout>
   
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"        
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/frame_layout_visible"
        
       >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageLegenda"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/legenda"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageSzukaj"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/szukaj"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageInfoObiekt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/infoObiekt"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageObszar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/obszar"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageOdswiez"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/odswiez"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` from first `FrameLayout` - it makes this `View` stick to right edge of the screen, so your second `FrameLayout` (one with `android:layout_toRightOf`) is pushed out of the screen. or maybe you can exchange it to `android:layout_toLeftOf`. also remove `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` from second one `FrameLayout`

Comment: Thank you, its' working but currently Frame Layouts are expanded to left part of screen.

Comment: make your second `FrameLayout` `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and your first layout `android:layout_toLeftOf` second one (in fact it should be `toStartOf`)